A manga about an alien thingy and an office girl
I read a manga about a girl and an alien. The girl found the alien injured so she took care of it. Then it turned out that alien can eat human waste, like pee. Long story short, they have babies in the end. Please help me find it, it's cute and spicy.

"Long story short they have babies in the end" - Wow. That escalated very very quickly.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And in roughly which year did you read it?

I swear this had been asked before but now I can't find it. Wild guess: The Strange Creature and I. If that's not it, could you try to remember additional details about the plot? Because I'm pretty sure this is not a unique story.

@BenBolker Generally speaking, Story identification questions are off topic on Anime&Manga.

@BLover143: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

The Strange Creature and I by Yana was suggested in the comments.
From one of the translations:

It's simply a story about a single woman meeting a tentacle monster, which leads to their somewhat stimulating life together.

Fair warning, the comic is tagged as pornographic. Here are two of the safer panels that indicate that it matches your memory of the creature's diet:
 
While they don't actually have kids together, she winds up carrying its eggs and "birthing" them because the human body makes a good incubator for his species.

Truthfully, most of the references I ran into (and the bits that I had to read to get the screencaps) indicate that it is a kind of cute story. But yeah, definitely pornographic. Consensual, but the genre rhymes with "pentacle rex".

"It's simply a story about a single woman meeting a tentacle monster, which leads to their somewhat stimulating life together."

@Shawn: Is that a summary from somewhere?

It's from the first page of the translation I dug up.

@Shawn: Ah, cool. I had yet to find a safe place to link to for it, or from which to quote a summary, but that sounds good. :-D

Yeah, the full panel with that quote in it probably shouldn't be included in an answer
